# I've Electron Project and I'd like to use vueJS into it

Tags: vue.js, electron, vue-component, electron-builder

I've Electron Project, but I can't use vuejs inside it...so how to use vuejs inside it? or I should install vue cli and install electron?

Comment: there are boilerplates like electron-vue you could use. https://simulatedgreg.gitbooks.io/electron-vue/content/en/?ref=madewithvuejs.com

Comment: @ChrisLi When I install electron-vue, I must move the files from the electron-project to electron-vue project?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I have seen currently is to create your Vue site first, with vue-cli 3, and then a vue-cli-plugin- but not electron-vue, which is stale.  Use vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder.  Starting with this, you can then add all the Vue you want.